# Removing Columns From ALL CSV Files in Specific Folder Then Outputting File With Date

Tags: bash, shell, csv, terminal, cut

I'm trying to automate some processes by using hazel app to move a file to a specific folder, execute a shell script on any csv in that folder, and then move it to another folder.  Right now the part I'm working on is the shell script.  I have been testing out the cut command in terminal on csvs but I'm not sure if its the same thing as a shell script since it doesnt seem to be working but what I have is:

`cut -d',' -f2,12 test.csv > campaigns-12-31-13.csv`

It looks for `test.csv` but I would like it to work with any csv, and it also exports it with the date `12-31-13` but I'm just trying to get it to export with whatever yesterdays date was.

How do I convert this to a shell script that will execute on any csv in the folder and so it adds the date for yesterday at the end of the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash

saveDir="saveCsv"
dd=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "yesterday")
for file in *.csv ; do
    bname=$(basename "$file" .csv)
    saveName="${saveDir}/${bname}-${dd}.csv"
    cut -d',' -f2,12 "$file" > "$saveName"
done
```

Comment: thanks! It ended up saying that there was an error executing the shell script.. here is what my setup looks like:http://i.imgur.com/BHsaqlK.png in the front is the hazel app, and in the back is the file/folder

Comment: @JoeBobby I cannot see any errors yet. What error message did you get? (I am not using mac, so I am not familiar with `hazel`..)

Comment: @JoeBobby You must create the directory `saveCsv` before you execute the script...